# Match peptide sequence to protein

Tags: r

I want to match peptide sequences to a given protein sequence. I have a lot of peptides per protein and some of them are overlapping as well. For an output I would like to have an new file which also tells me the position of the sequence in the protein.
Protein example:

> sp|O00170|AIP_HUMAN AH receptor-interacting protein OS=Homo sapiens GN=AIP PE=1 SV=2
>   MADIIARLREDGIQKRVIQEGRGELPDFQDGTKATFHYRTLHSDDEGTVLDDSRARGKPM
>   ELIIGKKFKLPVWETIVCTMREGEIAQFLCDIKHVVLYPLVAKSLRNIAVGKDPLEGQRH
>   CCGVAQMREHSSLGHADLDALQQNPQPLIFHMEMLKVESPGTYQQDPWAMTDEEKAKAVP
>   LIHQEGNRLYREGHVKEAAAKYYDAIACLKNLQMKEQPGSPEWIQLDQQITPLLLNYCQC
>   KLVVEEYYEVLDHCSSILNKYDDNVKAYFKRGKAHAAVWNAQEAQADFAKVLELDPALAP
>   VVSRELQALEARIRQKDEEDKARFRGIFSH
>   Peptides of that protein:
>   AHAAVWNAQEAQADFAK

AVPLIHQEGNR

EHSSLGHADLDALQQNPQPLIFHMEMLK

GELPDFQDGTK

NIAVGKDPLEGQR

RVIQEGRGELPDFQDGTK

TLHSDDEGTVLDDSR

VESPGTYQQDPWAMTDEEK

VLELDPALAPVVSR

I want to do that for many proteins, is there an easy solution?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I want to do this in R

Comment: Try [importing the FASTA files](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seqinr/versions/3.4-5/topics/read.fasta) and then running through them with [`grep`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you're using, but what's wrong with a simple string search in a loop?

That is the obvious solution unless you have to compute an obscene number of these in a short amount of time. (I guesstimate that if you need to do over 200 per second then you may start needing to consider a more optimised algorithm.)